# If $σ^2$ is the identity map from $G$ to $G$, prove that $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group which possesses an automorphism $σ$ such that $σ(g)=g$ if and only if $g=1$. If $σ^2$ is the identity map from $G$ to $G$, prove that $G$ is abelian.

This is what I got

Let $G$ be a finite group which possesses an automorphism $σ$ such that $σ(g)=g$ if and only if $g=1$. 
Assume that $σ^2$ is the identity map from $G$ to $G$, we will show that $G $is abelian.
Let $g,h∈G$, since $σ^2$ is the identity map from $G$ to $G$

$σ^2 (g)=g$

$σ^2 (h)=h$

And

$σ^2 (gh)=gh=σ^2 (g) σ^2 (h)$

Since $σ∈Aut(G)$, $σ$ is isomorphism (homophism and bijective) , so  $σ(gh)=σ(g)σ(h)=gh$. Thus, $gh=1=hg$. Hence, $G$ is abelian.

Did I do it correctly, I keep feeling I missed something.

Comment: Adding to Mikko's comment, I see problems in a sentence nearby. How does $\sigma$ being an automorphism imply that $\sigma(gh) = gh$?

Comment: Also note that you haven't used the finiteness of $G$, which isn't a good sign. The result doesn't hold for infinite groups.

Comment: why $\sigma(gh)=gh$?

Comment: I edited it, please check if it makes more sense?

Comment: Yes, you did a mistake when deriving $\sigma(gh)=gh$. How can you conclude this?

Comment: Also you did not use the hypothesis that $\sigma(g)\neq g$ if $g\neq 1$.

Comment: if you modify (correcting or erase) your try... the question is very good, as well the DonAntonio's answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hints:

$$\forall\,x,y,\in G\;,\;\;x^{-1}\sigma(x)=y^{-1}\sigma(y)\implies yx^{-1}=\sigma(y)\sigma(x)^{-1}=\sigma(yx^{-1})\stackrel{\text{given!}}\iff x=y$$

Thus, the map $\;x\mapsto x^{-1}\sigma(x)\;$ is bijective (why?) and thus

$$\forall a\in G\;\exists\,x_a\in G\;\;s.t.\;\; a=x_a^{-1}\sigma(x_a)$$

Try to take it from here...and remember: if $\;a\mapsto a^{-1}\;$ is a homomorphism, then $\;G\;$ is *abelian* ...

Comment: (+1) Awesome!!... you can use the "pigeon hole principle" for the surjectivity of $x\mapsto x^{-1}\sigma(x)$!!

Comment: how do you got $x^{−1}σ(x)=y^{−1}σ(y)$?

Comment: Well, the last line is a well-known characteristic of abelian groups, so thinking of $\;\sigma\;$ as being the well-known involution $\;x\to x^{-1}\;$ ...